SBペイメントの属性エラー
背景と環境
SBペイメントAPI型を使って、クレジットカード情報を登録したいです。
環境
python 3.10.0
Flask  2.3.2
Docker 27.1.1
※ローカル環境からリクエストを送っています
※sbペイメントのテスト環境を利用しています
関連コード
xmlを作成して、リクエストを送るメソッドです。
フォームからクレジットカード情報を受け取ります。
def register_credit_card():

    load_dotenv()

    form = credit_card_validation.CreditCardForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():

        #XML生成用の変数準備     
        merchant_id_value = os.getenv("SB_PAYMENT_MERCHIANT_ID")
        service_id_value  = os.getenv("SB_PAYMENT_SERVICE_ID")
        customer_id       = form.customer_ID.data
        card_number       = form.card_number.data
        expiry_date       = str(form.expiry_month.data) + str(form.expiry_year.data)
        security_code     = form.security_code.data
        ENCRYPT_FLG       = 0
        current_date      = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

        # SHA1ハッシュを作成
        hash_key = os.getenv("SB_PAYMENT_HASHKEY")
        concatenated_string = f"{merchant_id_value}{service_id_value}{customer_id}{card_number}{expiry_date}{security_code}{ENCRYPT_FLG}{current_date}{hash_key}"
        sps_hashcode_value = hashlib.sha1(concatenated_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        # XML文字列
        xml_payload = f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
        <sps-api-request id="MG02-00131-101">
            <merchant_id>{merchant_id_value}</merchant_id>
            <service_id>{service_id_value}</service_id>
            <cust_code>{customer_id}</cust_code>
            <pay_method_info>
                 <resrv1>{card_number}</resrv1>
                 <resrv2>{expiry_date}</resrv2>
                 <resrv3>{security_code}</resrv3>
            </pay_method_info>
            <encrypted_flg>{ENCRYPT_FLG}</encrypted_flg>
            <request_date>{current_date}</request_date>
            <sps_hashcode>{sps_hashcode_value}</sps_hashcode>
        </sps-api-request>'''
        
        # HTTPリクエストパラメータの準備
        api_url = "https://stbfep.sps-system.com/api/xmlapi.do"
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        }
        username = os.getenv("SB_BASIC_USERNAME")
        password = os.getenv("SB_BASIC_PASSWORD")

        # APIリクエスト送信
        response = requests.post(api_url, data=xml_payload.encode('shift_jis'), headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
        response_content = response.content.decode('shift_jis')

        return render_template('/page/mypage/member_information.html')

    return render_template('/page/mypage/member_information_edit/register_creditcard.html', form=form)

リクエストのペイロード
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
<sps-api-request id="MG02-00131-101">
     <merchant_id>xxxxx</merchant_id>
     <service_id>xxx</service_id>
     <cust_code>ee547eb4-69f8-4c91-81e1-253d284111ee</cust_code>
     <pay_method_info>
         <resrv1>0000111122223333</resrv1>
         <resrv2>042027</resrv2>
         <resrv3>8909</resrv3>
     </pay_method_info>
     <encrypted_flg>0</encrypted_flg>
     <request_date>20241008065859</request_date>
     <sps_hashcode>f0cd3310ec11dc3e2ab035cf14042303d36b51a1</sps_hashcode>
</sps-api-request>

問題
以下のようなエラーが返ってきます
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Shift_JIS' ?>
  <sps-api-response>
    <res_result>NG</res_result>
    <res_err_code>10104206</res_err_code>
    <res_date>20241008155859</res_date>
  </sps-api-response>

<res_err_code>の4,5桁目にあたる04が「属性エラー」を表しており、「格納可能なデータ型以外が指定された場合に発生」とのことです。
仮説&試したこと

エンコードありの場合となしの場合で試しましたが、変化はありませんでした。
数値型の部分をintパースしてみましたが、変化はありませんでした。

参考
API仕様書
レスポンスエラー仕様書

知見のある方、お助け下さい。

レスポンスの res_err_code ですが、
6-8桁目の 206 はクレジットカード決済の場合は「備考欄1」を示しているようです。
「備考欄1」は、リクエストの pay_method_info 内の resrv1 です。
こちらは型が M 、つまりマルチバイト文字列（BASE64エンコード必須）となっていますので、BASE64エンコードした値をセットしてみてはどうでしょうか。
例：
<resrv1>0000111122223333</resrv1>
↓
<resrv1>MDAwMDExMTEyMjIyMzMzMw==</resrv1>

※備考欄2と3にも同様の対処が必要かもしれません

ご回答ありがとうございます！
確かに6-8桁目はそのような意味だとありますね、気付きませんでした。
BASE64エンコードに関しては、暗号化の時は付けていたのですが今回失念していました、こちらは些末なミスで申し訳ないです。
エラー文が変わり、解決の方針も立ったので解決とさせていただきます。
大変貴重な情報ありがとうございます！
